# VSTS I can't create a new build definition, options are disabled

Tags: build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm using a free Microsoft Account (@outlook.com) on VSTS. I created my first proyect, configure it and make it works with CI/CD. Now, I'm creating a new proyect and I want to add a build definition, but I don't know why, all the options appears disabled.

No matter what I do, the Save button remains disabled.

¿There is a limited number of projects to use with CI/CD per account?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange behavior, but finally I found the solution: in the querystring params you need to remove the "path" parameter (path=%5C)

Reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/203956/build-definition-buttons-are-greyed-out.html